# JFrame to be displayed when the event occurs?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a JFrame which pops up when the event occurs. I am having a functionality which when the event occurs the JFrame pops up and if we click on that Frame it will open the corresponding frame, but the issue is when I am not clicking the popped up frame when the event occurs, if another event comes its displays the frame in the taskbar in a blinking state but not in an open state, I want to display the frame as it is without the frame blinking in the taskbar????
Any suggestions???

Comment: if AlexRs answer was what you're looking for, you should accept it by klicking the tick-mark next to it - that will be positive for your accept-rate and motivate peaple to help you on your other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already had such problem. try to call

frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

Then if you do not need this frame to appear on top **always** call

frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);