# Blink jframe in swing without transferring focus

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to blink my jframe's entry in taskbar but do not want it to get focused. I read about in on net and tried different solutions but none of them worked for me.

In my case I have a main jframe which has 2 buttons on click of which 2 jframes are opened. Both jframe listens to some event messages and on receiving of message it should blink if not focused.

I have tried following:

1. `frame.toFront();`
2. `frame.requestFocus();`
3. `frame.firePropertyChange();`
4. `frame.setVisible(true);`

They all worked well in blinking windows but the focus also gets transfered to that window which I don't want it do. How can I stop focus transfer? I have also tried calling `transferFocus();` after the above options but didn't worked.

I have searched on SO but didn't find the solution. The questions I found are

- [How can I flash the Windows taskbar using Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489255/using-swing-how-can-i-flash-the-windows-taskbar)
- [JFrame to be displayed when the event occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023281/jframe-to-be-displayed-when-the-event-occurs)

---

My current code:-

```
public void OnEvent(){
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();  
    if(!hasFocus()){
         toFront(); //requestFocus(); //setVisible(true); //firePropertyChange("",false,true);
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like you ought to be alternating the [icon image](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29) of your `JFrame` instead of transferring focus.

Comment: This seems like the exact sames question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489255/using-swing-how-can-i-flash-the-windows-taskbar.  Why not add a bounty to that question instead?

Comment: @jzd: because in that question OP has accepted an answer which does not solves my problem.

Comment: @mre: setting icon image doesn't blink window and my application hangs doing this.

Comment: I must have misunderstood you -- sorry. I thought you wanted the icon in the taskbar to "blink" whenever an event occurred and it didn't have focus! :)